# Store bot state bot framework v4 using Redis

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots

We are building a bot using Bot Framework SDK v4 for NodeJS which is basically a FAQ answerer. Bot state is currently stored inside Cosmos DB. However, we are considering switching to Redis because:
1. It is cheaper (correct me if I am wrong)
2. We don't actually need medium-long term user context persistance.

After searching in StackOverflow, we found a non-official, user made adapter for v3: [How to store bot state in Redis cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607271/how-to-store-bot-state-in-redis-cache)
Inside Microsoft documentation, we don't see any relevant orientation in NodeJS.

Does exist any official or non-offical connector for Redis in v4 for NodeJS? If not, it is very tedious to create a new one? Which would be the approach? We are open for other alternatives to Redis as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not aware of any Redis storage adapter for v4 Node SDK.. Did you already do a cost calculation for (managed) Redis versus CosmosDB with the lowest request unit amount. Have you considered using [Time to Live in CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live), to have the state automatically cleared?

Comment: Are you still working on this?